# Arranging drawables drawn on canvas

Tags: java, android

is there a way to arrange drawable drawen on canvas, before redrawing it? I mean setting which drawable will be drawn in the front, and which drawable will be drawn in the back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're drawn in the order you draw them. Just try drawing the one which sits in the back first, the front one last.

Comment: I know that, i need a better way

Comment: Well ... then you're looking for something like a z-index, right? As for as I know there's nothing like this. But if you know which z-index your drawables should have, just order them and draw them that way. It doesn't make a difference. Or write yourself a class which you give all your drawables and their z-index and make it draw them in the right order. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well you see, i want a drawable to be behind another drawable wich is drawn in a for loop. But i dont want it to be behind all drawables drawn in the loop, so putting the code first wont help me at all :/

Comment: And i also want to make that if (drawable1.y>drawble2.y) {bring drawable 1 to front}...

Comment: Still ... draw them that way. Call invalidate() and redraw your drawables in the right order. It's not possible to "move" something to front or to back. It's a canvas. You're drawing on it!

Comment: @mseo Not everything "just works" like that. Sometimes you are trying to do some tricky manipulation that requires you draw something before it is truly ready to be assigned to the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it is to have everything you draw define a z-index variable and collect everything you draw at a single point and put them in a list that you then order by the z-index before drawing it.

ex:

```
Interface IDrawable{
   int getZ();
   void draw();
}

class drawMe implements IDrawable{
    @overrider
    draw(){
    /// do my drawing
    }

    @override
    int getZ() {return z; }
}
```

in your drawing or main class

```
List<IDrawable> myList= new ArrayList();
myList.Add(new DrawMe());
```

and in your draw method

```
for(IDrawable draw : myList.OrderBy(z){
   draw.draw();
}
```

thats the concept anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can draw to a temporary canvas for drawing to the main canvas later.

```
Picture iconFrame = new Picture();
Canvas tempCanvas = iconFrame.beginRecording(width, height);
// width and height refer to the intended destination canvas size

...
// Any configuration before performing the draw should be done here

tempCanvas.drawPath(...);
tempCanvas.drawBitmap(...);
// Any required draw commands for this image should be done to tempCanvas

iconFrame.endRecording();

...
// Any other configuration or draw commands can be done here

iconFrame.draw(canvas);
// Assigns the content of tempCanvas to the top of the main Canvas
```

In my case, the PorterDuff manipulation of my image within a custom path only worked if it was done first because later draws corrupted it.